# SnackBar using ActionBar Theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-snackbar

I having this weird behavior with the styling of ActionBar and Snackbar. 
I have below theme for `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhiteDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGreen</item>
</style>
```

So, I am having white theme. And my `SnackBar` looks like this

[image]

But, whenever I add custom actionBarTheme, like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhiteDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorGreen</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ActionbarTheme</item>

</style>
<style name="ActionbarTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

My SnackBar looks like this

[image]

Why it is causing this behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are applying following style in your parent

```
<style name="ActionbarTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Your text color is black and your background is white.

EDIT:

To fix, you need to set textcolor as white and background black:

```
<style name="ActionbarTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all? OP wanted to know why applying their style to actionBarTheme changes their snackbar's theme and how to fix it.

Comment: @CarsonJ. the OP has asked "Why it is causing this behavior" , i have given the answer for the same, and I have edited my answer to satisfy his second question which is "how to fix it"

Answer (score -1):

change item name background to colorPrimary

```
<style name="ActionbarTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```